# How to receive and array of floats over a user defined message type?

Tags: ros, messages, array

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Example message type :

---

Request :
//request feature's 308 variables!

float64[308] features

Response :
//response Contains object type!

int64 object_type

---

After compiling with success all of this and the .cpp code. How do i access the float array ? There is some confusing code because the array created, that can be accessed in eclipse is like : <double, allocator>

Help needed!
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32146/how-to-receive-and-array-of-floats-over-a-user-defined-message-type-?/) by [ZsurzsaLaszlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2208/zsurzsalaszlo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-04-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're in C++, the type in the C++ message object is a `std::vector<double>`, which is traditionally accessed using subscripting:

`double x = foo[5];`

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-04-18**:
Actually fixed length arrays are now boost::array's, not std::vector's. See http://ros.org/wiki/msg for details on the mapping between types in message files and types in client libraries.

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-04-19**:
What he said.